# To what extent does national income measure social well being

Tags: social-welfare, national-income

National income does not measure social well being.
GDP is used to measure national income

Comment: Hi, this is a statement not a question. This is Q&A site not discussion forum if you want to open question it has to have some question in it (see our help center for details)  https://economics.stackexchange.com/help